# Scheme - How do you apply data structures to the combining of 2 Roman Numeral objects (letters & values) to produce a 2-character Roman Numeral?

Tags: data-structures, scheme, racket

I'm attempting to solve the following problem:

> Write a function called `form-rn` that consumes two `Roman-Numeral` objects (`digit1` and `digit2`) and produces the two-character `Roman-Numeral` represented by the values of `digit1` and `digit2` read from left to right. The string values of `digit1` and `digit2` must be a single letter (one of I, V, X, L, C, D, or M).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> (form-rn (make-Roman-numeral "C" 100) (make-Roman-numeral "C" 100))
> ```
>
> produces `(make-Roman-numeral "CC" 200)`, and
>
> ```
> (form-rn (make-Roman-numeral "X" 10) (make-Roman-numeral "L" 50))
> ```
>
> produces `(make-Roman-numeral "XL" 40)`.

So far I tried a few things:

```
(define II (make-Roman-numeral "II" 2))
(define IV (make-Roman-numeral "IV" 4))
```

This was in an attempt to produce Roman Numeral combinations but I realized that this probably isn't the approach I should be taking.

```
(make-Roman-numeral 'I 1)
(make-Roman-numeral 'V 5)
```

I thought maybe if I had to define each Roman numeral separately but its not supposed to be a single character like "I" its supposed to be a combo like "IV"

```
(define (form-rn digit1 digit2)
  (cond
    [(> digit1 digit2) (+ (Roman-numeral-value digit1) (Roman-numeral-value digit2))]))
```

I considered making conditions because the question says that if the first symbol is larger than the other, then the two symbols add up but if the second symbol is larger than the first, then the value of the larger symbol subtracts the value of the smaller symbol.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like you're trying to get help with a homework questions or similar exercise. This is permitted, but SO is not a code-writing service, so in order to get help, you should demonstrate an attempt to solve the problem. Post what you've tried so far, and [take a look at the help center for information on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What are the field names of the `Roman-numeral` struct? I see that the second field is `value`, but what's the name of the first?

Comment: The first field is `letters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track with your last attempt! A couple of notes

1. The question asks you to return a `Roman-numeral` object from your `form-rn` function, so you'll need to call `make-Roman-numeral` from inside it.
2. You need to handle the cases in which `digit1` is greater than `digit2` and the inverse separately.

In order to add the letters together, we can just use [`string-append`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string-append#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-append%29%29). To find the new `value`, then we can use `cond` to check which digit is greater. Then, we just need to take the two new values we've calculated and combine them into a new `Roman-numeral` object.

You can do this like so:

```
(define (form-rn digit1 digit2)
  (define new-letters (string-append (Roman-numeral-letters digit1) (Roman-numeral-letters digit2)))
  (define new-values
    (let ([value1 (Roman-numeral-value digit1)]
          [value2 (Roman-numeral-value digit2)])
      (cond
        [(> value1 value2)
         (+ value1 value2)]
        [else
         (- value2 value1)])))
  (make-Roman-numeral new-letters new-values))
```

Comment: Do I need to create distinct constructors for each combination of the symbols being considered (I, V, X, L, C, D, M)?

Comment: @ShagunChhikara Nope, this will handle all of them. I'll leave it as an exercise to you to figure out why. ;)

Comment: Alright. Also, don't I need to define each of the symbols and their values? and if so, will `(define C 100)` suffice?

Comment: @ShagunChhikara No, you don't need to do that, so long as the values passed into `form-rn` are correct.

Comment: I'm getting an error for the `(define new-values....)` section that states: "define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 2 extra parts" I don't understand why that is,